# Tabulate number of attacks within time and distance range

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial, temporal

This website has helped me with so much over the years, but I can't seem to figure this part out. I am working on modeling terrorist attacks in Afghanistan and want to create a new variable to reflect the clustering of attacks.  For each attack I want to calculate the number of attacks that fall into two range criteria, distance and time.

```
head(timedist_terr_talib, 15)
eventid      lat      lon     event1     Cluster_Num
1 20110104 32.07333 64.83389 2011-01-04     NA
2 20110107 31.00806 66.39806 2011-01-07     NA
3 20110112 34.53306 69.16611 2011-01-12     NA
4 20110112 34.87417 71.15278 2011-01-12     NA
5 20110114 31.65003 65.65002 2011-01-14     1
6 20110115 33.42977 66.21314 2011-01-15     0
7  20110116 35.95000 68.70000 2011-01-16    0
8  20110119 32.68556 68.23778 2011-01-19    0
9  20110119 34.08056 68.51917 2011-01-19    1
10 20110123 34.89000 71.18000 2011-01-23
11 20110128 34.53306 69.16611 2011-01-28
12 20110129 31.61767 65.67594 2011-01-29
13 20110131 35.03924 69.00633 2011-01-31
14 20110201 31.61767 65.67594 2011-02-01
15 20110207 31.48623 64.32139 2011-02-07
```

I want to create a new column whose values are the number of attacks that happened within the last 14 days and 100 km of that attack.

```
    event1 <- strptime(timedist_terr_talib$eventid, 
                       format="%Y%m%d", tz="UTC")
```

I found code that makes a matrix with the distance between each point:
http://eurekastatistics.com/calculating-a-distance-matrix-for-geographic-points-using-r/

```
#find dist in meters / 1000 to get km
#dis_talib_mat<-round(GeoDistanceInMetresMatrix(timedist_terr_talib) / 1000)
dis_talib_mat1 <- (GeoDistanceInMetresMatrix(timedist_terr_talib) / 1000)
```

And I have a matrix that calculates the time distance between every pair:

```
timediff_talib1<-t(outer(timedist_terr_talib$event1, 
         timedist_terr_talib$event1, difftime)) 
timediff_talib1<-timediff_talib1/(60*60*24)
```

So example for attack 1:4 are NA because the data does not have a complete 14 days. When I look at attack 5, I look at attacks 1:4 because they happened with 14 days. The distance matrix shows that 1 of those attacks was within 100 km. 
[image: distance matrix for terrorist attacks]
and manually count that there is 1 attack that is under 100 km away.

My current data set is 2813 attacks, so the running is slow, but if I could get the code for these 15 and apply it my set, I would be so happy!

Comment: I'd suggest looping through rows with `apply` using a function that determines the number of rows satisfying those two aspects. With each distance matrix, you would simply use a logical expression `sum(dis_talib_mat1 <= 100) `